# force wait in javascript

Tags: javascript, sleep

I want to force a function to wait 1 second before she continues after to do that in javascript .
For example:

```
function DoSomething(){
// wait 1 second
//continue w.e is this function does.
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If i understand you right , you need this:

```
setTimeout(DoSomething ,1000);
```

**Edit** , thanks to [Teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu):

```
function DoSomething (){
    setTimeout(ContinueDoSomething ,1000);
}
function ContinueDoSomething (){
    // ...
}
```

And even one more way , may be most effective in some cases:

```
function DoSomething (){
    setTimeout( function(){
        // ...
    },1000);
}
```

Comment: @PSR we don't know :)

Comment: some people dont know .So question posted in SO.Now you know

Comment: For clarity it's maybe useful to tell, that this should be put _outside_ of `DoSomething()`.

Comment: @Cherniv if u have any questions .you can post here.Then you can know

Comment: @Teemu you're absolutely right! i've edited my answer , thnx

Comment: this is not good enough, i have too many places where i call this function, i cant just create another function with the same name and change all the calls. i need something like $sleep(1000) or something like that. ( no such thing as $sleep, was just an example)

Comment: @OriGavrielRefael There's no `sleep()` in JavaScript, this is the **only** way.

Comment: @OriGavrielRefael , i've edited my answer , is this still not good?

Comment: i will do that if there is no other way